# Error while making a request from React server to node Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

Hey guys i was making a MERN stack project so the issue i am facing is that in action creater from react server i have to make a get request to node js server or in short

From http://localhost:3000/ i have to make request to the data i have in http://localhost:5000/api/currentuser

The data stored in nodejs server is `{"_id":"5d73fd9003b5302f6b013a46","googleid":"109463598810933991924","__v":0}`
which is being fetched from mongodb

So what i did is  inside my action creater file

i did like

```
import axios from "axios";
export const fetchuser = () => {
    return async(dispatch)=>{
       const res=await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/currentuser")
            dispatch({
                type:'fetchuser',
                payload:res.data

        })

    }

};
```

but then in my console i faced the error and it says

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/currentuser' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: You're running into a CORS issue. Have you setup CORS in with your express server? https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 1):

Without having the Express code it's hard to be confident but you likely need to configure the Express server to have CORS setup.

You can see the docs here for Express + CORS: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

```
var express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
var app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000"
  })
);
```

For more details on CORS in general, [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: hey but i am not getting my data back i mean when i go to http://localhost:5000/api/currentuser in my browser i get a response back but here after making get request by axios my data is an empty string  data:" "

Comment: Are you still getting the `blocked by CORS policy` error?

Comment: made a github repo if u wanna look out https://github.com/ratnabh/node-with-react

Answer (score 1):

This is cross origin issue.You have not provided access to http://localhost:3000/ in nodejs.

There are two simple ways,

**1. Simple way without any npm package**:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');

    // methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    / headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    next();
});
```

**2. Use cors npm package**:

Official document url
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

-To allow all domain/url

```
import cors from 'cors';
app.use(cors());
```

You will notice new header is being returned as
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

-To allow specific domain/urls,

```
import cors from 'cors';

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000/'
}));
```

Header will be,

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000

Comment: hey but i am not getting my data back i mean when i go to http://localhost:5000/api/currentuser in my browser i get a response back but here after making get request by axios my data is an empty string  data:" "

Comment: Could you please share me sample code of your logic?. so i can help you finding solution.

Comment: There is nothing in req.user. router.get('/api/currentuser',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.send(req.user)
})

Comment: Nodejs route try console.log(req.user); look whether there is anything in side it.

Comment: hey nikhil well m not sure if u tried this but first u have to go to the route localhost:5000/auth/google  then u will be signed in google account after that going on localhost:5000/api/currentuser manually in browser u will get details

Comment: so the same when i am going from react server to express server m not getting anyhting